# Enable ethtool statistics in a QEMU CentOS Guest OS

Tags: centos7, libvirt, qemu, virtual-network

I have a network interface available in a QEMU Guest OS running CentOS 7, and on the Host OS side it reports as:

```
$ virsh domiflist --domain mydomain
 Interface   Type        Source       Model    MAC
------------------------------------------------------------------
 -           vhostuser   /tmp/sock0   virtio   42:42:42:42:42:42
```

In the Guest OS:

```
# ethtool -S eth1
no stats available
```

And in the Host OS:

```
$ virsh domifstat --domain mydomain --interface "42:42:42:42:42:42"
error: Failed to get interface stats mydomain 42:42:42:42:42:42
error: internal error: Interface not found
```

Is it possible to enable detailed stats for this interface?